# How to use a Helper class in Lumen 8.0?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Is there anyone who can suggest me how can we use helper in Lumen 8.0 version? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I have followed below steps to add helper feature in my project in Lumen 8.0:

**First Step:** I have added "app/Helpers/MasterFunctionsHelper.php" string under "autoload" -> "files" array in `composer.json` file. Here "MasterFunctionsHelper" is my helper name:

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/MasterFunctionsHelper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

**Second step:** I have created "MasterFunctionsHelper.php" file at "app/Helpers/MasterFunctionsHelper.php". If "Helpers" directory is not exist then please create it in "app" directory.

**Third step:** created a class in "MasterFunctionsHelper.php" file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class MasterFunctionsHelper{

    public static function sayhello()
    {
        return "Hello Friends";
    }

}
```

**Forth step:** Opened controller file eg: "UsersController.php" and included "use App\Helpers\MasterFunctionsHelper;" and then called "MasterFunctionsHelper::sayhello();" function of helper class as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\MasterFunctionsHelper;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo MasterFunctionsHelper::sayhello();
    }

}
```

**Fifth step:** Opened command line and run below command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

When I run "index" action of "UsersController" in the browser then output was as:

**Hello Friends**

It worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thank you.